# Solving type erasure problems with an abstract type in a trait

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, type-erasure

I have a situation like this:

```
import scala.reflect._

trait SomeTrait {
  type T
  implicit def tag: ClassTag[T]
  def func2(x: Any) = x match {
    case x: T => "foo"
    case _ => "bar"
  }
}

case class SomeCaseClass()

class SomeClass extends SomeTrait {
  type T = SomeCaseClass
  implicit def tag = scala.reflect.classTag[SomeCaseClass]
  val x = SomeCaseClass()
  def func1() = func2(x)
}

object Main extends App {
  val someClass = new SomeClass()
  someClass.func1()
}
```

However, the `someClass.func1()` call yields,

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at SomeClass.tag(...)
  at SomeClass.tag(...)
  at SomeClass.tag(...)
  //etc.
```

as if it's recursively calling itself. If I remove the ClassTag, then I have the type erasure warning, which I need to fix. Additionally, I need `SomeTrait` to remain a trait, thus `[T : ClassTag]` as a type parameter to is not an option. Does anyone know how I can avoid the type erasure warning with an abstract type in a trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [reflect api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html):

```scala
def classTag[T](implicit ctag: ClassTag[T]): ClassTag[T]
```

When you call:

```
implicit def tag = scala.reflect.classTag[SomeCaseClass]
```

your execution is:

```
implicit def tag = scala.reflect.classTag[SomeCaseClass](tag)
```

and you receive never ending loop.

Try (in object SomeCase implicit is not visible):

```scala
object SomeCase {
  val tagSomeCaseClass =  scala.reflect.classTag[SomeCaseClass]
}


class SomeClass extends SomeTrait {
  type T = SomeCaseClass
  implicit def tag = SomeCase.tagSomeCaseClass
  val x = SomeCaseClass()
  def func1() = func2(x)
}
```

And I checked - it works for me:
 scala>  val someClass = new SomeClass()
        someClass: SomeClass = SomeClass@371a67ec

```
    scala> someClass.func1()
    res0: String = foo

    scala> someClass.func2(4)
    res1: String = bar

    scala> someClass.func2("String")
    res2: String = bar

    scala> someClass.func2(SomeCaseClass())
    res3: String = foo
```

I do not know how to suppress warning...

Comment: Thanks! If you're talking about the "The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time" warning, then that's not that big of a deal IMO. It's the type erasure one that was causing me problems.